# iOS table cells with fixed images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I'm developing an ios app and am trying to achieve an effect in a tableview like the following website: http://www.poormet.com/

There is a couple of ways I have thought about this. I know you can set the background of the tableview which remains fixed and then you could possibly swap the images as the text box covers the image. This is limited though as you can only have one image on the screen at a time which is not what I'm after.

I also thought about pushing the image down for each cell as the cell moves up, but for this case I couldn't set the frames position in the scrollViewDidScroll method(which I used to obtain the frames actual position in the tableview).

I was also wondering if there was anything similar in ios to what you have with div's in html where you can specify an image to be fixed.

How would I go about doing this? If you guys need any more information let me know, I'm new to posting on this site.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't set the frames position in the `scrollViewDidScroll`?

Comment: So the scrollViewDidScroll method is called whenever you move the table. I also have a custom view cell with an imageView property called backgroundImg. I grab the frame in the scrollViewDidScroll method and try to set it, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: The frame doesn't change when you scroll, the scroll view's contentOffset changes. You need to use the frame and the contentOffset together to figure out where the cell is on screen (for instance, when the frame.origin.y equals contentOffset.y the top of the cell is at the top of the table view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this through `scrollViewDidScroll`. I'm guessing you already have subclassed `UITableViewCell` and made your own, so heres a thought:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    for(UITableViewCell *cell in [yourTableView visibleCells])
    {
        //I haven't tried this `convertRect` method, and the views might be in the
        //wrong order, but I'm sure you'll figure it out. It should solve this.
        CGRect position = [yourTableView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view]
        [((YourCustomCell*)cell) updateImage:position];
    }
}
```

Then in your custom cell class, add a method named `-(void)updateImage:(CGRect)position;` which will now contain the location of the cell, and you can move the image whatever way you want, as I'm guessing you already have a method for. I.E:

```
-(void)updateImage:(CGRect)position
{
    //change the location of the image inside self.imageView here
}
```

Comment: Yeah for some reason the values for the frame aren't being updated in the scrollViewDidScroll method. I have no idea why, but I may be missing some basic thing in my code

Comment: @user3108995 I haven't tried it myself, but you can try the method `[tableView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];`. I think it would solve your problem.

Comment: cool thanks, the problem was due to my terrible naming of variables and me getting confused. I went with this solution in the end as it worked but would be interested to see if there are any other ways to do this

Comment: @user3108995, I think this, or something similar to this is probably the best way to go. I did it slightly differently, passing the contentOffset to the cell's updateImage method, and I only needed 2 lines of code in that method to make it work -- I don't think any other way, like your first idea would be nearly as easy.